# Tiny font on Android Studio with high-density display

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu

Here is what the UI looks like on a high-density display :

[image]

For your information, I'm on Ubuntu 18.10 and using latest stable version of Android Studio (3.2.1)

I've been trying many ways to fix this issue, including :
- Following [these instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/troubleshoot#scaling_factor_settings)
- Running `xrandr --dpi 192` before launching Android Studio
- Adding `-Dsun.java2d.uiScale.enabled=true` to studio64.vmoptions file
- Using Ubuntu Tweak tool to update the scaling factor
- Solutions from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029436/enable-fractional-scaling-for-ubuntu-18-04)
- Overriding font size in Android Studio settings

But nothing helped, apart from last one but I got a weird display with some oversized buttons.

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: this is still an issue on Ubuntu 19.04 and Android studio 3.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I installed Android Studio 3.4.2 on Ubuntu 19.04/Dell XPS, I also got tiny fonts.  At the same time IntelliJ 2019.1.3 had normal fonts.  Usually Android Studio releases are based on older versions of IntelliJ, and I thought that installing Android Studio 3.5 Beta 5, that is based on a newer version of ItelliJ, may fix the problem.  And indeed, there is no problem with fonts in Android Studio 3.5 Beta 5 on Ubuntu 19.04/Dell XPS.